# Missive amount of empty materials in the scene

Tags: modeling, materials

Is there a way to get rid of these empty materials ? Now i am manually going one by one and deleted. my scene is big and i just deleted a bunch of unused materials and now i want to apply single material to the whole scene but now I am left with hundreds of these empty materials on every single object and some of them override main material randomly [image]

Comment: you can remove them all at once but for several objects I don't know if it's possible, probably with a script